# Storing a private key to decrypt a file from SFTP

Tags: marketing-cloud

I need to decrypt a file on our SFTP with a custom private key.

But when attempting to store a private key I get an error message stating that only public keys can be stored.

The file transfer activity also gives me no option to select my own key and forces me to use exact targets own private key.

**How can I store and utilize my own private key to decrypt a file in the enhanced SFTP? Is this even possible?**

Answer (score 0):

If my assumption is right then I don't think you can store the private keys at this point on your own.

It seems like you'll need to reach out to Salesforce professional services team to configure your own private key.

Here is the reference [article](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/175650/file-transfer-activity-encrypt-and-decrypt-with-pgp).